# py.test: how to get the current test's name from the setup method?

Tags: python, pytest

I am using py.test and wonder if/how it is possible to retrieve the name of the currently executed test within the `setup` method that is invoked before running each test. Consider this code:

```
class TestSomething(object):

    def setup(self):
        test_name = ...

    def teardown(self):
        pass

    def test_the_power(self):
        assert "foo" != "bar"

    def test_something_else(self):
        assert True
```

Right before `TestSomething.test_the_power` becomes executed, I would like to have access to this name in `setup` as outlined in the code via `test_name = ...` so that `test_name` == `"TestSomething.test_the_power"`.

Actually, in `setup`, I allocate some resource for each test. In the end, looking at the resources that have been created by various unit tests, I would like to be able to see which one was created by which test. Best thing would be to just use the test name upon creation of the resource.

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7798114/248616) unittest.TestCase.id()

Comment: Does that work with pytest-style tests (ie standalone functions rather than methods on a class which inherits from TestCase)?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can also do this using the [Request Fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#request) like this:

```
def test_name1(request):
    testname = request.node.name
    assert testname == 'test_name1'
```

Comment: **This is the general-purpose answer,** equally applicable to both test functions _and_ test methods. While py.test documentation is _usually_ spectacular, its documentation for the `request` fixture is unusually awful. The `request.node` attribute is documented only as "underlying collection node (depends on current request scope)." That's it. I absolutely _never_ would have found this – and doubt anyone else would have either. Bravo, froggy Daniel!

Comment: Note however when the test function has been parametrized, `request.node.name` contains the unique name with parameters, e.g. `test_name[param-other_param]`. Therefore it is _safer_ to always use [`request.node.originalname`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.python.Function.originalname), which provides the original function name intact. Also note this is available starting from py.test 3.0.

Comment: There is no mention of the request fixture at your link.

Comment: @julen but if the test is *not* parameterized, `originalname` is `None`

Comment: `Note however when the test function has been parametrized, request.node.name contains the unique name with parameters, e.g. test_name[param-other_param].` For me, that's what I want, because I want a unique output filename.

Comment: You can also get the module name with `request.module.__name__`.

Comment: Just noting that the documentation is now much clearer on the use of this: https://docs.pytest.org/en/documentation-restructure/how-to/fixture.html#fixtures-can-introspect-the-requesting-test-context

Answer (score 72):

You can also use the `PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST` environment variable set by pytest for each test case.

[PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST environment variable](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html?highlight=PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST#pytest-current-test-environment-variable)

To get just the test name:

```
os.environ.get('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST').split(':')[-1].split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: Wow, this should be the simplest answer and should be accepted

Comment: Just tested with pytest 4.0.2 and it does work.  You might also want to add `.strip('[]')` to remove more extraneous info.

PS: You need to add the code _inside_ the test case.

Comment: I mean the env varia le not define. Do we need to config pytest somewhere for this?

Comment: not sure what you mean..  that env variable is defined by Pytest when running tests. See example here (variable values in gray to the right of the code): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yg8r8R3LBxG9RtEcktcWYKyPiWR6LrNJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, now I see that it's from the `setup` method..  not sure if that env var is defined at that point.   an alternative is to just run that piece of code (or call it as a separate function) in the beginning of the test.

Comment: Thank you verymuch great tips, I get the testname on to my conftest.py ... thanks again for the link and trick.

Comment: Love this answer!

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen to this particular issue and I've been searching for at least some hours. Thank Joao

Comment: Note

The contents of PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST is meant to be human readable and the actual format can be changed between releases (even bug fixes) so it shouldn’t be relied on for scripting or automation.

Comment: Is it reliable in the context when multiple test scenario are running in parallel, for example with pytest-xdist?

Comment: Haven't tried w/ `xdist`. If you want to be certain, use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34732269/205075), using `request.node.name`.

Answer (score 23):

The `setup` and `teardown` methods seem to be legacy methods for supporting tests written for other frameworks, e.g. nose. The native `pytest` methods are called `setup_method` as well as `teardown_method` which receive the currently executed test method as an argument. Hence, what I want to achieve, can be written like so:

```
class TestSomething(object):

    def setup_method(self, method):
        print "\n%s:%s" % (type(self).__name__, method.__name__)

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        pass

    def test_the_power(self):
        assert "foo" != "bar"

    def test_something_else(self):
        assert True
```

The output of `py.test -s` then is:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.3
plugins: cov
collected 2 items 

test_pytest.py 
TestSomething:test_the_power
.
TestSomething:test_something_else
.

=========================== 2 passed in 0.03 seconds ===========================
```

Answer (score 12):

### Short answer:

- Use fixture called `request`
- This fixture has the following interesting attributes:

  - `request.node.originalname` = the name of the function/method
  - `request.node.name` = name of the function/method and ids of the parameters
  - `request.node.nodeid` = relative path to the test file, name of the test class (if in a class), name of the function/method and ids of the parameters

---

### Long answer:

I inspected the content of `request.node`. Here are the most interesting attributes I found:

```
class TestClass:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("arg", ["a"])
    def test_stuff(self, request, arg):
        print("originalname:", request.node.originalname)
        print("name:", request.node.name)
        print("nodeid:", request.node.nodeid)
```

Prints the following:

```
 originalname: test_stuff
 name: test_stuff[a]
 nodeid: relative/path/to/test_things.py::TestClass::test_stuff[a]
```

NodeID is the most promising if you want to completely identify the test (including the parameters). Note that if the test is as a function (instead of in a class), the class name (`::TestClass`) is simply missing.

You can parse `nodeid` as you wish, for example:

```
components = request.node.nodeid.split("::")
filename = components[0]
test_class = components[1] if len(components) == 3 else None
test_func_with_params = components[-1]
test_func = test_func_with_params.split('[')[0]
test_params = test_func_with_params.split('[')[1][:-1].split('-')
```

In my example this results to:

```
filename = 'relative/path/to/test_things.py'
test_class = 'TestClass'
test_func = 'test_stuff'
test_params = ['a']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
# content of conftest.py

@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def test_log(request):
    # Here logging is used, you can use whatever you want to use for logs
    log.info("STARTED Test '{}'".format(request.node.name))  

    def fin():
        log.info("COMPLETED Test '{}' \n".format(request.node.name))

    request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have multiple tests, in which case...

```
test_names = [n for n in dir(self) if n.startswith('test_')]
```

...will give you all the functions and instance variables that begin with "test_" in `self`. As long as you don't have any variables named "test_something" this will work.

You can also define a method `setup_method(self, method)` instead of `setup(self)` and that will be called before each test method invocation. Using this, you're simply given each method as a parameter. See: http://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html

Comment: All methods representing py.test tests start with `test`. What I need here is py.test API, because py.test has collected all the tests beforehand (basically the way you suggested here) and already knows which test is to be run now. I just don't know the right question to ask py.test :-)

Comment: Comment after your edit: I don't want to simply have a list of all the methods starting with "test_". From this list, I am after the one name / the method of the test being executed *right now*. And this only the py.test internals can tell.

Comment: I think you want `setup_method` instead of just `setup`

Comment: I want `setup`, because this is what py.test calls for initializing each test.

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely the right pointer. I was using py.test with `setup` and `teardown` for a long time now without realizing that those methods are more or less supported only for legacy reasons (this is right, isn't it?). In order to answer the question with a code example, I have submitted my own answer. I hope this is fine with you.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the inspect module are try.

```
import inspect

def foo():
    print "My name is: ", inspect.stack()[0][3]


foo()
```

Output: `My name is:  foo`

Comment: Called from within the `setup` method this obviously returns `setup`.

Answer (score 1):

Try my little wrapper function which returns the full name of the test, the file and the test name. You can use whichever you like later.
I used it within conftest.py where fixtures do not work as far as I know.

```
def get_current_test():
    full_name = os.environ.get('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST').split(' ')[0]
    test_file = full_name.split("::")[0].split('/')[-1].split('.py')[0]
    test_name = full_name.split("::")[1]

    return full_name, test_file, test_name
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `type(self).__name__` perhaps?

Comment: In my example, this would only provide `TestSomething`. I'm mainly after the second part of the name :)