# How to find the test ID for parametrized tests during execution of the test?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test that is parametrized with `@pytest.mark.parametrize` so that the same test function can be executed with different parameters. `@pytest.mark.parametrize` uses the `ids` argument defined as a function so that a custom test ID is generated for each parameter.

My test function writes a file to disk that tabulates the differences between actual and expected results for the given parameter. I would like to report the test ID in the file.

Is there an API I can call which will tell me what test ID applies to a particular execution of the test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [py.test: how to get the current test's name from the setup method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726954/py-test-how-to-get-the-current-tests-name-from-the-setup-method)

Comment: Please see this comment in proposed duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726954/py-test-how-to-get-the-current-tests-name-from-the-setup-method#comment69402327_34732269. `request.node.name` will do the trick.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `request.node.callspec.id` from the [Request Fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#request).

---

But take note that the value depends on whether the `ids` function "*generates a string representation to make part of the test ID*". From pytest's docs on [Different options for test IDs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids), the stringified version of the param is normally added to the test ID.

For example, if the `ids` function generates an ID that does not include the stringified param or does not depend on anything else:

```py
import random
def generate_random_id(param) -> str:
    return f'{random.randint(1,100)}'

testdata = ['argA', 'argB']

@pytest.mark.parametrize('param', testdata, ids=generate_random_id)
def test_foo(param, request):
    print(request.node.callspec.id)
```

Then you would get the generated ID as-is:

```
tests/test_a.py::test_foo[78] PASSED      
tests/test_a.py::test_foo[10] PASSED      

============================ PASSES =============================
_________________________ test_foo[78] __________________________
--------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------
78
_________________________ test_foo[10] __________________________
--------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------
10
```

If the `ids` function includes the string representation of the param, then you would need some sort of delimiter to manually split the param and the test ID:

```py
import random
def generate_random_id(param):
    test_id = random.randint(1, 100)
    return f'{param}-{test_id}'  

testdata = ['argA', 'argB']

@pytest.mark.parametrize('param', testdata, ids=generate_random_id)
def test_foo(param, request):
    param, test_id = request.node.callspec.id.split('-')
    print(param)
    print(test_id)
```

```
tests/test_a.py::test_foo[argA-43] PASSED 
tests/test_a.py::test_foo[argB-37] PASSED 

============================ PASSES =============================
_______________________ test_foo[argA-43] _______________________
--------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------
argA
43
_______________________ test_foo[argB-37] _______________________
--------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------
argB
37
```

If there are multiple params, then it becomes more complicated, since all the param + `ids` combinations are concatenated together to create the full Test ID. You will need a separate delimiter different from `-`:

```py
import random
def generate_random_id(param):
    test_id = random.randint(1, 100)
    return f'{param}+{test_id}'  # Use '+' to separate param+ID

testdata = [
    ('argA', 'argB'),
    ('argC', 'argD'),
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('param1, param2', testdata, ids=generate_random_id)
def test_foo(param1, param2, request):
    print(request.node.callspec.id)
    params = request.node.callspec.id.split('-')
    for a_param in params:
        param, test_id = a_param.split('+')
        print(param)
        print(test_id)
```

```
tests/test_a.py::test_foo[argA+70-argB+25] PASSED         
tests/test_a.py::test_foo[argC+97-argD+30] PASSED          

===================================== PASSES =====================================
___________________________ test_foo[argA+70-argB+25] ____________________________
------------------------------ Captured stdout call ------------------------------
argA+70-argB+25
argA
70
argB
25
___________________________ test_foo[argC+97-argD+30] ____________________________
------------------------------ Captured stdout call ------------------------------
argC+97-argD+30
argC
97
argD
30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
os.environ.get('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST')
```

To get the current parametrize execution.

A similar question was already asked and has a lot of other options: [py.test: how to get the current test's name from the setup method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726954/py-test-how-to-get-the-current-tests-name-from-the-setup-method)

If you are looking for a more dynamic way of doing it, take a look in: https://hackebrot.github.io/pytest-tricks/param_id_func/, is a plugin for pytest that may easy the pain.