# How to get testcase name in python + nosetests?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, nose

I need **testcase name** into my **teardown method**, is there any way to get testcase name in python + nosetest?

```
def test_google(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get("http://www.google.com")

def tearDown(self):
    print ("Need to get test case name")
    self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: what should be the result ?

Comment: @Bhansa: output should be testcase name i.e  test_google

Comment: [See this answer, may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797442/how-to-get-currently-running-testcase-name-from-testsuite-in-unittest)

Comment: @Bhansa: ya tried it dosen't helps me.
I am running my test from command prompt.

nosetests -v -s <filename>.py

Answer (score 0):

try
print self._testMethodName
it will print the testcase name